# Nokogiri multiple domains

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Is it possible to do multi domain searches using Nokogiri. I am aware you can do multiple Xpath/CSS searches for a single domain/page but multi domain?

For example I want to scrape http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/#specifications and http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications

**My Code**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications"))

#Grab our product specifications
data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec li')

#Modify our data
lines = data.map(&:text)

#Create the Spreadsheet
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.name = 'My First Worksheet'

#Output our data  to the Spreadsheet
lines.each.with_index do |line, i|                                                        
  sheet1[i, 0] = line                                                                     
end    

book.write 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/output.xls'
```

Comment: Check http://anemone.rubyforge.org/information-and-examples.html to filter on domains to apply your CSS/XPath selectors.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't know about websites or "domains". It only knows about HTML or XML source. What it does with that source is up to you. As is, this question is nonsensical.

Comment: anemone is a site spidering program, which is capable of much more than simply grabbing pages, and is probably overkill at this point.

Comment: Yes I have to crawl before I learn to walk :D

Comment: You may want to consider using Mechanize, which can follow links. It uses Nokogiri internally for parsing, and you have access to the Nokogiri document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri has no concept of URLs, it only knows about a String or IO stream of XML or HTML. You're confusing OpenURI's purpose with Nokogiri's.

If you want to read from multiple sites, simply loop over the URLs, and pass the current URL to OpenURI to `open` the page:

```
%w[
  http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/#specifications 
  http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications
].each do |url|

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  # do somethng with the document...
end
```

OpenURI will read the page, and pass its contents to Nokogiri for parsing. Nokogiri will still only see one page at a time, because that's all it is passed by OpenURI.

Comment: Thank you Mr Tin Man, that explains why I didn't encounter any information on searching multi domains.